# Estimating the probability of next failure?

Tags: r, probability, distributions, data-mining, predictive-models

I have some data about how some components failed. They can either be replaced in whole or have some of their sub-components repaired. I would like to know if there is a way to fit a failure model to the underlying failure distribution and computing reliability of my components.

I read about Survival Analysis and was very interested in it (because it also takes into account the components that have "survived" post observation period), but unfortunately, it assumes complete component failures (whereas my situation deals with component-repairs as well). Is there any related area that deals with the repair situation?

The data I have is the following (output of `dput` in `R`):

```
c(43044461L, 48043852L, 39290306L, 50335198L, 47604418L, 9875530L, 
1738141L, 46301014L, 6477432L, 7372344L, 49950268L, 29007573L, 
46118058L, 12292465L, 238234L, 9277711L, 34570342L, 37371531L, 
28471868L, 11157523L, 50931534L, 26694512L, 29961599L, 2457994L, 
33987131L, 20175414L, 1577647L, 769861L, 1249158L, 32224970L, 
9409192L, 34033673L, 32297668L, 27564068L, 2730862L, 19241848L, 
18254820L, 39185109L, 33662797L, 12003705L, 39384318L, 26484711L, 
15432679L, 32281540L, 34839587L, 385860L, 9973362L, 21839720L, 
37642093L, 33886689L, 17704281L, 33337960L, 13913748L, 32304197L, 
33636487L, 22603695L, 25718240L, 32181213L, 32264085L, 5881735L, 
35120576L, 5527473L, 23051956L, 23054083L, 22961394L, 22962199L, 
4632371L, 2757599L, 9663000L, 29225898L, 29233148L, 29237159L, 
29435753L, 1107666L, 26138387L, 26163543L, 26215242L, 7561251L, 
26218513L, 26221383L, 30476747L, 26222109L, 27602048L, 27607598L, 
27610958L, 27684885L, 1782502L, 25654474L, 19616668L, 10155706L, 
1736017L, 27025910L, 10117992L, 20506415L, 11541948L, 27586115L, 
26692258L, 16235808L, 14966802L, 15974788L, 2014068L, 7215767L, 
8022835L, 22321409L, 22524449L, 9940245L, 12431361L, 6723321L, 
1337135L, 14011887L, 26516990L, 19894509L, 23580559L, 25837938L, 
25421604L, 25260751L, 1014468L, 17600421L, 18969565L, 19501830L, 
11816652L, 11832654L, 18962013L, 18967493L, 19044885L, 10660220L, 
7152965L, 25676536L, 182572L, 14811759L, 18464712L, 12164906L, 
19920052L, 12495744L, 16548293L, 16625312L, 9665000L, 284178L, 
284213L, 284143L, 284178L, 284178L, 284178L, 2992895L, 9475072L, 
4444603L, 10436184L, 3108530L, 8261921L, 3493839L, 8603179L, 
563679L, 7788458L, 12934577L, 16212035L, 14764962L, 3274975L, 
18208633L, 2661185L, 12233593L, 19688931L, 3176516L, 10347964L, 
3176445L, 7326030L, 816261L, 17698452L, 8280151L, 9832881L, 18059503L, 
16362051L, 18559410L, 3016907L, 18821969L, 250538L, 18937854L, 
20460554L, 11466655L, 19841035L, 5666426L, 11466795L, 9351749L, 
14202233L, 8395799L, 2469799L, 11120915L, 2007822L, 2251827L, 
10425100L, 12864547L, 17400937L, 12224074L, 14425083L, 7790951L, 
7790951L, 18092421L, 249048L, 14389608L, 14389643L, 14389643L, 
14303313L, 14303313L, 184829L, 184797L, 184972L, 13871348L, 13871243L, 
13871383L, 13871278L, 99619L, 99514L, 98467L, 98467L, 98429L, 
98467L, 98467L, 98432L, 98432L, 98432L, 98432L, 98432L, 11372596L, 
9926436L, 204260L, 2492418L, 2492418L, 2960708L, 9660687L, 8180564L, 
53600L, 11428758L, 9942851L, 2648374L, 1899270L, 1812870L, 1812870L, 
1812870L, 1812870L, 1812870L, 1812870L, 5811703L, 3334565L, 11639886L, 
5776214L, 5386427L, 2057170L, 853094L, 4856466L, 7488042L, 10322886L, 
71544L, 2208165L, 2035661L, 2121240L, 2121744L, 2122268L, 4393081L, 
2481686L, 4767429L, 2696190L, 7631815L, 3464979L, 2737688L, 11709771L, 
9311182L, 6952803L, 210747L, 8219827L, 508306L, 4713143L, 6456962L, 
5299429L, 8969430L, 2290297L, 117516L, 2980892L, 2048608L, 7152852L, 
396062L, 396062L, 3459981L, 3691834L, 3834119L, 6950281L, 1431240L, 
15124240L, 1292511L, 14712416L, 14629719L, 15120090L, 3284021L, 
1485496L, 2420495L)
```

Answer (score 1):

Survival analysis doesn't necessarily require complete failure - you could model time to any failure (component or complete), time to failure of a sub-component, or time to complete failure. So long as you are model time to some event, any event will work.

If you want to model time to failure of a sub-component only, then complete failure would probably be a competing risk (assuming that once the entire component fails the sub-components are no longer able to fail, since they are no longer in use), and you may need to use methods which can account for that.

EDIT:
In my comment, I suggest using a time-dependent variable of the form repairtime which changes value based on whether a repair has happened and when that repair happens. I can't find a good example of this method online.

Another approach is to use the counting process format, and I found a good example of that online, so I'm adding it here. Conceptually it is not very complicated - basically, you create multiple observations for each individual based on times during which the values of the covariates are the same and between which the values of one or more covariates changes. So, if you had a part (say, ID=1) that was repaired at time t=5, you would have one observation with (ID=1, repair = 0) that spans time [0,5) and a second observation with (ID = 1, repair=1) that spans time [5,t). You could easily allow repair to take any value. You need to be concerned about repeated measures, but analysis of counting process data takes care of this.

The example is here http://www.ms.uky.edu/~mai/data.5  and provides the dataset and very straightforward R code: coxph( Surv(start, stop, event) ~ age + transplant).  In this example, the event is death and the time-dependent variable is heart transplant. So the interpretation for the log of the coefficient for transplant is, the hazard ratio for the effect of receiving a transplant or not, at a specific time t, adjusted for age. This example makes the proportional hazards assumption for the time-dependent variable, transplant.

The interpretation of the repairtime approach is basically the same as the interpretation of the counting process approach, and the repairtime approach also makes the proportional hazards assumption for repairtime. The difference between using either of these two approaches versus just putting the count of repairs in your model by itself is that putting the repairs into the model alone assumes that repairs happen at baseline. That assumption can lead to length time bias - parts which need to be repaired earlier may also be more likely to fail in the long run compared to parts which don't fail until much later (or possibly vice versa).

If you wanted to allow the hazard ratio to vary over time, you could also put the repairs in the model with repair*time interaction terms. But for multiple repairs of multiple parts, this could get a bit complicated (I would suggest separate main and interaction terms for each repair) and require a lot of terms. To interpret that you would need to calculate the hazard ratio separately at any/all time points of interest, or plot the hazard ratios over time. Then you could see the effect of repairs versus no repairs at specific points in time. I'm also not quite sure how to ensure that this approach doesn't end up with assuming the repairs happen at baseline.

Comment: Let me clarify with more details. In my scenario, a failure is: complete component failure, sub-component failure and yes, a sub-component failure will indicate a complete component failure. What I was worried about was the notion of **repairs**. When a component is repaired and put back into operation again, wouldn't it be incorrect to ignore the fact that this is an old device that was repaired (which means, its lifetime was affected by the repair)?

Comment: Ah. You could handle this by including a variable on the repaired status of the component. This could vary over time and take the value 0 until the component is repaired and 1 at all time points after repair - or even increase to 2 if given a second repair. This would be a time-dependent variable, so there are some nuances to the analysis. Paul Allison's book Survival Analysis using the SAS System gives an example of this type of analysis using recidivism, which may be helpful to read.

Comment: +1 for your time. This is great! Thank you for this information. However, I don't have access to the book as of now so it might be a while before I can look into this. If you don't mind, can you show me perhaps a hypothetical example in R (either using the data I have in my question) or some other smaller dataset? I am very interested in knowing how I can leverage the latter case you described i.e., increase a time dependent variable to indicate the number of repairs a component experienced so far.

Comment: In general, for a time-dependent number of repairs, you need two (or more) variables: repaired (0,1), repairtime1 (time of repair 1). Then repairstatus at time t  equals 0 if repaired = 0 or time<repairtime1, or 1 if time>=repairtime1. This should be extendable to multiple repairs by adding more repairtime variables, although I have not done that before. Repairstatus is used in your Cox model and needs a value at all failure times in your dataset - in SAS you do this by calculating the value of repairstatus in your regression proc. In R I'm not sure how it's done but I will try to find out.

Comment: I haven't used R for survival analysis very often before - I usually use SAS. So, someone else may be better able to give you an example, but I will try to find/put together some sample code in the next day or so if I can.

Comment: I don't want to trouble you too much. I am much more interested in the interpretation than the implementation. I am ok with a SAS example too - I will try to find a trial copy somewhere that I can play with. Thank you for your time.